# How can we assume a bool Property on a Generic<T> class , where T is a auto generated LINQ2SQL class

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, generics

I am doing a CRUD operation on Database generated class(using LINQ2SQL) in my WPF application. All of my DB tables have IsDelete property exists. So I want to define an abstract/interface class to do the SoftDelete(). My question here is, how can I define my Generic class in such a way as to access T.IsDelete = true ? or in code I want to do something like below

```
public abstract class CRUDOperations <T> : where T is????
{
  .......
  protected virtual SoftDelete()
  {
     T.IsDeleted = true;
  }
}
```

Where T is DB generated Table classes by LINQ To SQL (DBML), which I cant impose an Interface or base class on top of it?. Or is there a technique in DB to have a base table which has the same Base/Derive concepts of C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare this on an interface:

```
public interface ICanDelete {
    bool IsDeleted {get;set;}
}
```

and let implicit interface implementation work its magic. Then the question becomes: "how to let it know that my entities implement this interface?". Two options:

- add a partial class per entity (in a different file):

  ```
  partial class Customer : ICanDelete {}
  partial class Order : ICanDelete {}
  ```
- edit the dbml to specify this interface as the base class:

  ```
  <Database EntityBase="Some.NameSpace.ICanDelete" ... >
  ```

  (this makes LINQ-to-SQL's code-generation add the `: Some.NameSpace.ICanDelete` for you)

Then just use this interface in the generic clause:

```
where T : ICanDelete
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Define ISoftDelete

```
public interface ISoftDelete
{
  bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create partial classes for all your entities

```
public partial class MyLinqEntity : ISoftDelete { }
public partial class MyOtherLinqEntity : ISoftDelete { }
public partial class MyFurtherLinqEntity : ISoftDelete { }
```

3) Add your interface to the generic type restriction

```
public abstract class CRUDOperations <T> : where T is ISoftDelete
```

Comment: Thanks, Looks like a solution but does Step2 is a huge work for me on all my Table Classes right?

Comment: Yep.  There are other ways of doing this in the designer, but I prefer this method as I'll have all these partials I can use to modify my entities.  Also, if I have to ditch the DBML and start over again (happens more than I would like) I won't have to redo all my customization work.

Comment: IIRC, you can't do this in the designer - you have to hand-edit the dbml.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the Database generated classes derived from Entity?

Comment: this is what I can see MyTableClass: INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Sounds like EF; the question is LINQ-to-SQL